# Get value from recycler view Adapter to activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the layout as below. And I want to get all the data from the "quantity view" (from textview between "+" and "-" button) to my activity after the "proceed" button click.

[image]

I tried few of the answers but could not get the expected result. Can I get Some Help.
I have added a interface on adapter...

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(String id, String amount);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

and on the quantity change of the "quantity view" i tried to get the data from the adapter to activity

```
holder.quantityView.setOnQuantityChangeListener(new QuantityView.OnQuantityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQuantityChanged(int oldQuantity, int newQuantity, boolean programmatically) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(pricingPOJO.getId(), newQuantity + "");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLimitReached() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: Having a method in your adapter that returns the current list of the items (in the adapter) should be okay for fetching all the data back to the activity/fragment

Comment: can you help me with the function to get the list of values of recycler items in an array....i am not able to get the right logic thank you

Comment: You need to implement "OnItemClickListener" to your activity.

Comment: @FalduJaldeep yes i did that...but i only get the value of one item in the recycler...i want the value of all the items there

Comment: Do you need selected items value or all the values that are available into recycler view?

Comment: best to get the values that are not zero in the textview....but getting all also will do the job...i will manage that in the server side

Comment: @unownsp one way would be as stated by Faldu Jaldeep, onItemClickListener update the respect item of your pojo. So whenever there is a change your pojo would get updated and you have collection of all the data.

Comment: @unownsp if I am not wrong, you are trying to get all the values from recycler view when you hit on proceed button. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: yes you are right @Karrthik

Comment: Create a separate array for the selected items and pass it when the user clicks on the proceed button.

Comment: @unownsp your best way would be add a new key called count in your pojo and default it to 0. update array item's count using position key which provided by recycerview Adapter.

Comment: @FalduJaldeep thank you...i think now i get it..

Comment: @unownsp Best of luck... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a Map of selected position to values like:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> positionToValueMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then in `OnBindViewHolder` do this:

get your value like:

```
yourValue = positionToValueMap.get(getAdapterPosition());
```

set your value like:

```
positionToValueMap.put(getAdapterPosition(), yourValue);
```

then create getter method for `positionToValueMap`   in adapter class and call the getter from your fragment/activity.
You are all done.